# Angular 5 activatedroute with having to nest service call in the subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a angular 5 app with routing in which my app.routes.module.ts file handles the route for criminal

```
{ path: 'criminal', component: CriminalComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
```

However, in navigating to here, I'm upgrading an old site to angular and I'm for now using the generated URL links example:

```
<td href="/criminal/?UserID=67694&AppID=4&AppGroupID=13&AM&LoginKey=202088840" >CR Programmers</a></td>
```

I wasn't sure if I should be tampering with the route file for all these querystring parameters so for the **MENU** generation I was placing it in there.

```
ngOnInit(): void {  .... }
```

So inside OnInit I know I need to parse out the querystring
Then I need to make a service call passing in all the params

When I had them separate, it seems that conditional if on if there WAS a menu was NOT processed in time and no menu service call would happen.

Is there a way to have my service call subscribe to the query params section?

```
    this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap
        .map((params: Params) => params.params)
        .subscribe((params) => {
            if (params && params['UserID']) {
                let UserID = params['UserID'];
                let AppID = params['AppID'];
                console.log('UserID', UserID);
                console.log('AppID', AppID);
                this.hasMenu = 1;
                console.log('hasmenu', this.hasMenu)

                this.arsSevice.getMenu() //will pass params
                .subscribe(
                result => {
                    this.menuA = result["data"].Menu1Items
                    this.menuB = result["data"].Menu2Items
                    this.menuC = result["data"].Menu3Items
                    this.menuD = result["data"].Menu4Items
                    this.menuE = result["data"].Menu5Items

                },
                error => {
                    console.log('menu error', error);
                })


            }
        });
```

Basically above code has the getMenu() call ( which is not currently passing params)

I would LIKE to not have it NESTED inside

this part i would prefer to do like this

```
  if (this.hasMenu == 1) {
     this.arsSevice.getMenu()
                .subscribe(
                result => {
                    this.menuA = result["data"].Menu1Items
                    this.menuB = result["data"].Menu2Items
                    this.menuC = result["data"].Menu3Items
                    this.menuD = result["data"].Menu4Items
                    this.menuE = result["data"].Menu5Items

                },
                error => {
                    console.log('menu error', error);
                })

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter to do conditional checking and flatMap/map to chain them up

```
 this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap
    .map((params: Params) => params.params)
    .filter((params) => params && params['UserID'])
    .flatMap(params=>{
            ..... your other operation
           return this.arsSevice.getMenu()
     }).map( result => {
                this.menuA = result["data"].Menu1Items
                this.menuB = result["data"].Menu2Items
                this.menuC = result["data"].Menu3Items
                this.menuD = result["data"].Menu4Items
                this.menuE = result["data"].Menu5Items
}).subscribe()
```